# How fast are the Pacific Rim Jaegers?

Tags: pacific-rim

Striker Eureka is said to be the fastest Jaeger with a stat card speed rating of '10' out of a scale I'm assuming of 1-10. We see Striker running through thigh deep water in Hong Kong Bay to engage two Kaiju in battle but we have no reference points to gauge how fast 'he' is actually moving.

[image: Striker Eureka stat card showing Speed 10]

Gypsy Danger with a speed rating of 7 is shown walking, jogging and even running through the streets of Hong Kong where we have buildings and city blocks to gauge distance to get a sense of how fast 'she' can actually move across the ground. Her walking speed seems to be about 30-40 mph and while jogging she covered 2 Hong Kong city blocks in about 4-5 seconds.

[image: Gypsy Danger stat card showing Speed 7]

How fast can they move in recognizable miles per hour?

Comment: I really wish they established a good statistical base during the write, but I suspect they were freeballing the 'ratings'.

Comment: The entire film is an example of this trope http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TravelingAtTheSpeedOfPlot. Everything should take much longer but then the film would be boring to watch.

Comment: @Richard -I especially liked Gipsy's flying 'superman' punch of Leatherback on the pier. That was at least a 300' jump.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To establish a Jaeger speed we can use the human body as a guide.

We know that the average human walking speed ranges from 1-3 mph. The average human running speed depends on whether it's a sprint or running long distance. Sprint speed average is about 15 mph and long distance speed is 8 mph. Top level human running speeds top out near 28 mph.

Considering that a Jaeger is built to approximate the human form and movement potential and that they're 43 times taller than a human, this would mean that a Jaeger stride is 43 times longer as well. Also, properly piloted Jaegers seem to move with the same fluidity as the human body.

With these factors in play we can extrapolate a reasonable approximation of the speed potential of a Jaeger by multiplying the numbers;

Walking speed would be approx. 43-129 mph;
Jogging speed would be approx. 344 mph;
Sprinting speed would range from 645-1204 mph

Taking into consideration speed obstacles such as lack of traction, trip hazards, wind turbulence and drag, uneven terrain features such as hills and valleys, we can reasonably cut those 'potential' numbers in half to arrive at 'real-world' speeds.

Walking speed would be approx. 22-65 mph;
Jogging speed would be approx. 172 mph;
Sprinting speed would range from 323-602 mph

In summary: A Jaeger can do the highway speed limit just by walking fast, outrun most helicopters while jogging and outrun all but jet aircraft in a sprint.

Comment: I would add that we never see a Jager at full sprint - their shear mass seems to prevent it (I'm sure Striker was at full speed in the harbour). My suspicion is they don't have the power/weight ratio to move much faster than a fast jog.

Comment: @Liath -That's a good point. Another factor about their weight is that everything crumbles under their mass. It would be like a human trying to run/sprint in sand. (Too much give and not enough good traction/surface stability to drive against.